# Can I prove a multivariable limit like this?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

This limit I am trying to evaluate is this.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}=\frac{x^{3} + y^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

First I converted to polar coordinates

So the limit became

$$\lim_{r\to 0}=\frac{(r\cos(θ))^{3} + (r\sin(θ))^{3}}{r^{2}}$$

After simplifying I was left with

$$\lim_{r\to 0}= r(\cos^{3}(θ) + \sin^{3}(θ))$$

Next I said the expression $$\cos^{3}(θ) + \sin^{3}(θ)$$ was always in between $-1$ and $1$. I said this because $\sin^{3}(θ)$ and $\cos^{3}(θ)$ are both always in between $-1$ and $1$ that means that there sum must also be in between $-2$ and $2$.

So I said that

$$\lim_{r\to 0}= r*c$$

where $c$ is a real number coming from the interval $[-2,2]$

Then I determined that the limit must be zero

$$\lim_{r\to 0}= r*c=0*c=0$$

because any real number multiplied by zero must be 0.

I'm not sure If I'm allowed to sub in the constant so I was wondering if someone could tell me if your allowed to do that. If I'm not what other ways can I evaluate this limit?

Comment: As a typesetting note, `*` is rarely used except for nonstandard multiplication or arbitrary group operations.  `\cdot` or `\times` are more common to see for multiplication.  $r\cdot c$ or $r\times c$ as opposed to $r*c$

Comment: Hint: Can you see a way to find lower and upper bounds for $r(\cos^{3}\theta + \sin^{3}\theta)$? If so, you may be able to cast the problem in a form to apply the squeeze theorem. :)

Comment: Your proof is logically correct. You could use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition to make last step more formal.

Comment: That would do, yes, since $r > 0$ except at the origin. (Technically, you also need to show $|\cos^{3}\theta + \sin^{3}\theta| \leq 1$; this isn't difficult, but it's even easier to see $|\cos^{3}\theta + \sin^{3}\theta| \leq 2$, which suffices for your purposes.)

Comment: Yeah I just realized my mistake. I corrected it above

Comment: @Amey: That may be dicey, since the "$c$" doesn't stand for an actual real number, but an arbitrary member of a bounded set. (That is, the proposed argument, as stated, is not invoking "the limit of a product is the product of the limits", so its validity may be debatable.)

Comment: I was wondering is substituting the constant wrong if you know that the term your working with is bounded?

Comment: @user262291: It's not logically wrong, but may require separate proof (probably using the squeeze theorem).

Comment: @Bernard yeah I corrected it in my question above

Comment: Regarding formatting, you can just write  A B between dollar signs to get $A B$ for a product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew said in the comment, you can do final touch with the squeeze theorem.
Since you know that $f(\theta)= \sin^3 (\theta)+\cos^3 (\theta)$ is bounded above and below by some constants $M_1$ and $M_2$ you have $M_1<f(\theta)<M_2$ so we have $\lim_{r\to 0} M_1r \leq \lim_{r\to 0} rf(\theta) \leq \lim_{r\to 0} M_2r$ and then follows $0 \leq \lim_{r\to 0} rf(\theta) \leq 0$ and then $\lim_{r\to 0} rf(\theta)=0$ follows.

Comment: That is, $|x^3+y^3|=$ $r^3|\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta|\leq $ $r^3\cdot 2=2 r|x^2+y^2|$  so for $r\ne 0$ we have $|(x^3+y^3)/(x^2+y^2)|\leq  2 r.$

Comment: We can also note that if $z=\max (|x|,|y|)$ then $|x^3+y^3|\leq$ $ |x|^3+|y^3|\leq$ $ z x^2+z y^2=z(x^2+y^2).$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

If $(x,y) \neq  (0,0)$ then we have
${|x^3+y^3| \over x^2+y^2} = {\|(x,y)\|_3^3 \over \|(x,y)\|_2^2 }$.

It is straightforward to show that $\|(x,y)\|_3 \le \sqrt[3]{2} \|(x,y)\|_2$,
and
so
$\|(x,y)\|_3^3 \le 2 \|(x,y)\|_2^3 = (\|(x,y)\|_2^2 ) 2 \|(x,y)\|_2$, and
so
${|x^3+y^3| \over x^2+y^2} \le 2 \|(x,y)\|_2$.

Hence $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} {|x^3+y^3| \over x^2+y^2} = 0$.

Comment: What does the notation $||(x,y)||^{3}_{3}$ stand for?

Comment: In general (with $p \ge 1$) we have $\|(x,y)\|_p = \sqrt[p]{x^p+y^p}$.